# Select in Postgresql with project SUM Agregate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have problem in SQL below:

1. The field `mdoc_valor` can not duplicate or add, since it is a single value and is not part of the aggregation, only the `mprd_valor` field should add as it is in a daughter table. that is, the `modc_valor` field is in the parent table and the `mprd_valor` field is in a child table.
2. What is happening is that the `mdoc_valor` field is adding values ​​according to aggregation and I do not want this field to be changed.

---

```
select dpto_codigo,
       dpto_descricao,
       sum(mdoc_valor) as Liquido,
       sum(mprd_valor) as Compras_Bruta
from movdctos
inner join movprodd1017 on (mdoc_transacao=mprd_transacao)
inner join produtos on (prod_codigo=mprd_prod_codigo)
inner join departamentos on (prod_dpto_codigo=dpto_codigo)
where mdoc_datamvto>=CAST('2017-10-31' AS DATE) and
mdoc_datamvto<=CAST('2017-10-31' AS DATE) and
mdoc_dcto_tipo in ('EAQ') 
group by 
dpto_codigo,
dpto_descricao
```

Comment: Give example data where you get the behaviour you don't want.  Re-code your SQL to always use `table.field` to make it possible for *us* to understand what comes from where.

Answer (score 0):

Based on table names and your questions, it seems that you don't need to sum the `mdoc_valor` field. I removed the aggregation from this field, added it to the GROUP BY and also added aliasing of tables to improve readability.

```
select dpto.dpto_codigo,
   dpto.dpto_descricao,
   mdoc.mdoc_valor as Liquido,
   sum(mprd.mprd_valor) as Compras_Bruta
from movdctos mdoc
inner join movprodd1017 mprd on (mdoc.mdoc_transacao=mprd.mprd_transacao)
inner join produtos prod on (prod.prod_codigo=mprd.mprd_prod_codigo)
inner join departamentos dpto on (prod.prod_dpto_codigo=dpto.dpto_codigo)
where mdoc.mdoc_datamvto>=CAST('2017-10-31' AS DATE) and
mdoc.mdoc_datamvto<=CAST('2017-10-31' AS DATE) and
mdoc.mdoc_dcto_tipo in ('EAQ') 
group by 
dpto.dpto_codigo,
dpto.dpto_descricao,
mdoc.mdoc_valor;
```

This should give you `SUM(mprd_valor)` for every combination of `dpto_codigo`, `dpto_descricao` and `mdoc_valor`(renamed to Liquido).

Comment: Sure. Improved them.